# Concatenate column with identical characters between rows

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Another difficult-to-search problem:

I want all the data in a certain column to appear in a single cell elsewhere. `CONCATENATE` does that, but not the way I need. So far I have

```
=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!A3:A999)
```

I've seen other spreadsheets in which the cell inserts an @ before each value and space afterward. That's exactly what I want to do here. I'd steal the formula directly from one of those sheets but I can't seem to find any at present, and can't figure out how to search for exactly this without getting 500 results that just mention the words "google sheets" somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need is this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(IF(LEN(Sheet1!A3:A), "@"&Sheet1!A3:A, ),,999^99)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is a pity that you did not attach your source data and the desired result explicitly. I mean sample range, not 1000 cells. But as far as I understand, you would like to get this formula, based on [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) feature:

```
=CONCATENATE(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT(CONCAT("@";Sheet1!A3:A999); " ")))
```

Am I right?

Note! If you want to exclude empty cells from the range, you can use [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) as follows:

```
=CONCATENATE(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT(CONCAT("@";FILTER(Sheet1!A3:A999; NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A3:A999)))); " ")))
```

Comment: this will only do if all cells in column A are not empty - otherwise its: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIBwf.png

Comment: @player0 - I have added this case to the answer, if you are interested in.